# How would you call a person who shares their private life details way more often than others?

Tags: psychology

Most of the time I encounter it in form of excessively sharing their personal life details through social media without any obvious goal like money or popularity.

I have an impression that I've heard this word before but somehow can't find it.

Comment: Isn't emotional person what you're looking for? How about  unreserved one?

Comment: @haha I just found a word "effusive" and I think it might be the one

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not what you're looking for, but *over-sharer* might fit the bill. [*To overshare*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overshare) means

> to disclose too much (personal information) or too many (details) about oneself

<sub>(Dictionary.com)</sub>

This isn't limited to social media, but the term *share* is commonly used in that context.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm looking for something unrelated to social media, but focused on private life details sharing, e.g. if a person shares interesting facts about fishes – that's not the thing.

Comment: I like the word "effusive", maybe it's the one